# LWC - Checkbox read-only, reset

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm pretty new to this LWC environment and trying to change jQuery to the LWC friendly.

So this is about the checkbox where you can select all the options, but when you click on the "None of the above" It will make all the options read-only and unchecked.

[image]

[image]

So this was the code behind (no LWC)

```
<HTML>
    <body>

      <form id="numberForm">
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1"/>1
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2"/>2
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3"/>3
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4"/>4
        <input type="checkbox" value="5"/>5
        <br/>
      </form><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="" onclick="enableDisableAll(this);"/>None of the above
      
      <script src="script.js">
      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

---

```
  function enableDisableAll(e) {      
    var own = e;
    var form = document.getElementById("numberForm");
    var elements = form.elements;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++) {
      if(own !== elements[i] ){
        if(own.checked == true){
          elements[i].disabled = true;
          elements[i].checked = false;
        }else{ 
          elements[i].disabled = false;  
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And now I've change index.html to LWC but still having a hard time changing script.js

```
<template>
   <form id="numberForm">
      <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="1" value="1"></lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="2" value="2"></lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="3" value="3"></lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="4" value="4"></lightning-input>
      <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="5" value="5"></lightning-input>
    </form>
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="None of the above" value="none" onclick={enableDisableAll}>    </lightning-input>
```

Any idea or comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't comment too much on your code, however, there are some things you need to consider when migrating to LWC.

for starters, `document.getElementById("numberForm")` is not supported.
Instead, use template.querySelector's. for more on this, refer to
[Access elements a component owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_dom_work.html)

as per your choice of displaying checkboxes, instead of hardcoding checkboxes in your template, consider using another approach, and declare an array of objects for your different checkboxes, and use the [template directives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives) to render them dynamically. This will allow you to directly access properties from a constant vs having to query your DOM and modify DOM properties, and then modify your js constants

find bellow an example of how to do this and adding a change handler to update your input checkboxes.

template.html

```
<template for:each={checkboxes} for:item="chk">
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label={chk.label} value={chk.value} checked={checked} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

template.js

```
checkboxes = [
{label: 'checkbox 1', value: 'some value', checked: false, name: 'some name'}]

handleChange(e) {
  this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.map( chx => { return { ...chx, checked: (e.target.name === chx.name) ? e.target.checked : chx.checked }}
}
```

Comment: I've recently implemented something like the above utilizing [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - which I wouldn't recommend in hindsight, because it doesn't go well in exchange with @AuraEnabled methods. Could you elaborate a little bit, how you'd do this with both JSON and arrays?!

Comment: Thx, glls, really appreciate it (although strictly speaking you are still not using JSON ;-)

Comment: indeed - should rephrase to array of objects or something like that. ill amend shortly

Comment: Thanks glls for the help. This will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple no need onclick fuction

html:

```
<template for:each={checkboxes} for:item="chk">
<lightning-input class="checkBoxFld" type="checkbox" label={chk.label} value={chk.value} checked={checked}></lightning-input>
```

css:

```
.checkBoxFld{ pointer-event : none;}
```

js:

checkboxes = [
{label: 'checkbox 1', value: 'some value', checked: checked, name: 'some name'}]